# filter 3D signal using medilt on each component separately gives different results than filtering the signal at once

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using medfilt to filter a 3 dimensional array (a,b,c)

```
        import scipy as sp
        import numpy as np
        a = np.random.rand(180000)
        b = np.random.rand(180000)
        c = np.random.rand(180000)
```

if I filter the 3 components separatly like this

```
        x = sp.signal.medfilt(a,3)
        y = sp.signal.medfilt(b, 3)
        z = sp.signal.medfilt(c, 3)
```

and then combine them into a numpy array

```
        out1 = np.array([x,y,z]).T
```

I get a different result than when I filter the 3 components at the same time...

```
        sigIn = np.array([a,b,c]).T
        out2 = sp.signal.medfilt(sigIn,3)
```

Could you please explain me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `2D` stacked array, we need to use [`2D` version of `median filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.medfilt2d.html), with the list of kernel sizes along each dimension.

Thus, we would have -

```
from scipy.signal import medfilt2d

out2 = medfilt2d(sigIn,[3,1])
```

Sample run -

```
In [49]: n = 4
    ...: a = np.random.rand(n)
    ...: b = np.random.rand(n)
    ...: c = np.random.rand(n)
    ...: 
    ...: x = medfilt(a,3)
    ...: y = medfilt(b, 3)
    ...: z = medfilt(c, 3)
    ...: 
    ...: out1 = np.array([x,y,z]).T
    ...: 

In [53]: from scipy.signal import medfilt2d

In [54]: sigIn = np.array([a,b,c]).T

In [55]: out2 = medfilt2d(sigIn,[3,1])

In [56]: np.allclose(out1, out2)
Out[56]: True
```

As a sidenote, we can use `np.column_stack` for the stacking operation and thus avoid that `transpose`, like so -

```
sigIn = np.column_stack((a,b,c))
```